# Get a Department Percent Contribution of Total Sales

Tags: powerbi, sum, dax, cumulative-sum

```
    Table = opportunity
    Dimension Field = Territory
    Measure Field = AnnualSales
```

I want a measure that will take a territories SUM(AnnualSales) and see what percentage it makes of All territories SUM(AnnualSales) would be.  I have not been able to accomplish this based off the articles I've read so far.  Any help is greatly appreciated

My results would look something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see results in a table of visualization:

create this measure: CALCULATE(SUM(AnnualSales))

then, drag Territory field in a table, add the new measure created in the table and then go to visualization editor right click on measure and click on show results as a percent of column total.

Waiting your answer ... :)

Regards

Comment: Thank you cristobal.huraz!  worked perfectly.  I actually didn't need to create the new measure.  I just added in the AnnualSales measure as SUM and right clicked and it produced the same results.  Thanks again for the support!

Comment: To take it a step further, lets say now I apply a filter on the territory, that % of total adjusts to only what is shown within the filtered territories.  I want the summary to be on all of the territories AnnualSales, regardless of the filter, and then when I do filter, the % of total is calculated on the shown territories' AnnualSales against the overall company's AnnualSales.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I set out with the following.

cm_TotalEstAnnualSales = Calculate(Sum(opportunity[Est. Revenue (Annualized)]),All(opportunity))

cm_PctofTotalEstAnnualSales = Divide(SUM(opportunity[Est. Revenue (Annualized)]),[cm_TotalEstAnnualSales],0)

Thanks for the tips here!